# Using bootstrap icons in grid as command buttons

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, webforms

I am trying to figure out how to use the bootstrap icons as buttons with CommandNames in a GridTemplateColumn or a GridButtonColumn.

```
                <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="Commands">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" CssClass="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign" runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

<telerik:GridButtonColumn ButtonCssClass="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign" />
```

At the very least I am trying to make a bootstrap icon act as a button but not look like a button, just the icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the `asp:Button` for a `asp:LinkButton`

```
<ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete" runat="server" CssClass="glyphicon-remove-sign"/>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: This works great, now I just need to get rid of the blue and underlining. Any ideas?

Comment: Try add this line in your CSS `a.glyphicon{text-decoration: none; color: TheColorYouWant; } .glyphicon:hover { text-decoration:none; color: TheColorYouWant;}`